# Argument for staying on Rails instead of migrating to .net MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I work for a Rails SaaS platform that was recently acquired by a primarily Microsoft shop. They are pushing the issue we need to rewrite the entire application in .NET. It's very clear they know nothing about Ruby or Rails and are simply scared of something out of their norm and have heard the common thought of "Ruby / Rails isn't scalable long term".

My questions are these:

- Is this still true today in Rails 5.2?
- Is Rails really not scalable? Do they have a valid argument stating we should rebuild into .NET?
- Is there any counter argument saying we are fine staying in Rails for the long term?

Comment: "Is Rails really not scalable" is a red herring.  If you ever get large enough where this becomes a real problem, you'll have the money and resources available to fix it then.  Don't try to fix a problem you don't have.

Comment: That said, if the shop that acquired you really wants to do a full rewrite (an endeavor that is usually [ill-advised](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/)), you can look on it as a résumé-building exercise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True about the resume builder - I do love Ruby though and enjoy working in it. Not sure I will find the same joy in .net

Comment: "If you ever get large enough where this becomes a real problem", at what point does it start becoming an issue. Is it with active record or jsut the slowness of Ruby? @RobertHarvey

Comment: When the CPU and disk utilization on all of your machines is consistently 80% or higher instead of 20%, and you can't scale out by adding more machines.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is fine; it's very much like Rails, and much of your new development would probably be in the browser anyway, given the state of modern software development.  Trust me, you *want* this to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, yes its slow.

https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/

However, as noted performance of the language probably isn't very important compared to things like good database design and code written with scaleablity in mind.

More likely they are a .net shop and just want everything in .net. They must like it a *lot* to want a rewrite as these things rarely pay off.

Take it as an opportunity to learn a new (better) language and to refactor all the technical debt you have accumulated.

Answer (score 6):

You can give counter examples of large scale applications.

With its 40.1 million users, GitHub is one of them. [It is written using Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub#Company_history), and it doesn't seem to suffer a lot with the technological choices when it comes to scalability (unlike Facebook, which did hit serious issues with the original choice of PHP).

---

But, of course, all this is technical. The choice of your new boss to use ASP.NET MVC is political, and the scalability reason was given to you because your boss believes that it is more polite to give any reason than just to tell you that his choice is his choice, and your opinion doesn't matter. So before starting any argument with your employer about which technology is better and why, make sure your resume is up to date on Careers.SE. Good luck.

Comment: I agree that it's a political situation. Does a shop that is primarily Microsoft want to continue supporting a Rails app and staffing Rails developers long-term? Certainly the human resource costs would be lower if they standardized on a single platform.

Comment: I highly doubt that they are still using Rails. Do you have source?